# Ayuda con LINQ en C# con group by

Tags: c#, sql, linq-to-sql

Hola espero me puedan ayudar en como convertir esta consulta de Sql Server en Linq

```
select p.correlativo, SUM(p.precio_compra) from Productos p 
where p.tipo_compra > 0
group by p.correlativo, p.fecha_compra
```

Esta consulta me retorna esto

```
4   0.99  este es un unico registro
5   5.00  este son dos registros
6   3.00  este son dos registros
```

Hice esto en C# usando Linq y si me arroja tres grupos y al iterar dentro me arroja todos los registros y quisiera solo los que grupos en si

```
List<Productos> listatmp = (from p in db.Productos
                            where p.tipo_compra != null
                            select p).ToList();
var final = listatmp.GroupBy(x => x.correlativo);
```

Porque también no se como insertar la suma por grupo, así como en la consulta sql.
Espero me puedan ayudar, les agradecería mucho

Comment: Si lo resolviste podes colocar tu codigo como respuesta para que otra persona lo pueda consultar. Si nadie te ayudo es porque no han visto la pregunta.

Comment: Bienvenido, es importante revisar [ask] que te brinda información acerca de 

como formular preguntas en el sitio,
No olvides realizar el [tour]  del sitio, saludos.